# How would I include 0 values in a Spark Scala SQL Query?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to loop through a dataframe and count how many times a date occurs within specific date ranges. The code is working fine. The only problem is, if it doesn't find any dates in a given date range, it's not including that date range with a value of 0 in the resultant dataframe. Let me show you an example:

here is my input dataframe,

[image: input dataframe]

and here is my bin range dataframe,

[image: bin range dataframe]

The SQL query I'm using is this:

```scala
val countSql = """
SELECT concat(date_format(c.st_dt,'MM-dd-yyyy'),' -- ',date_format(c.end_dt,'MM-dd-yyyy')) as date_range, c.bin_count
FROM (
(SELECT
b.st_dt, b.end_dt, count(1) as bin_count
FROM
(select to_date(input_date,'MM-dd-yyyy') as date_input , * from input_table) a
left join
(select to_date(start_date,'MM-dd-yyyy') as st_dt, to_date(end_date,'MM-dd-yyyy') as end_dt from bin_range ) b
on
a.date_input >= b.st_dt and a.date_input < b.end_dt
group by 1,2) ) c"""
```

The way the code is right now, it would return an empty dataframe because no dates from the input dataframe fall in the bin ranges provided. But I would like a row for each bin range and a corresponding 0 value next to it, if nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `range_table` on the left side of the join if you want all the ranges to appear in your final result. Also, you could simplfy it for somthing like this :

```sql
SELECT  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(r.st_dt,'MM-dd-yyyy'),' -- ', DATE_FORMAT(r.end_dt,'MM-dd-yyyy')) AS date_range, 
        COUNT(i.date_input) AS bin_count
FROM    bin_range r
LEFT JOIN input_table i
ON      i.date_input >= r.st_dt AND i.date_input < r.end_dt
GROUP BY CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(r.st_dt,'MM-dd-yyyy'),' -- ', DATE_FORMAT(r.end_dt,'MM-dd-yyyy'))
```